# NSAlert duplicates "help" menu

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nsalert

I have a very simple modal code in my project:

```
/*!
 * @method      popUpDialog:
 * @abstract    Triggers a pop-up window.
 */
- (void)popUpDialog:(NSString *)prompt {
    NSAlert * alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Message"];
    [alert setInformativeText:prompt];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

I am using this in the `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator;` method to warn the users the migration was successful. Then it duplicates the help menu. It seems to be happening only with Mavericks. My app works in Snow Leopard just fine.

[image: Doubled help]

Any ideas why that happens?

Sorry, I couldn't find anything similar at Stack Overflow. I tested and it only happens if the message is displayed, so I think this code is the culprit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you are doing your thing within `init`, `awakeFromNib`, or `applicationWillFinishLaunching`.

In this case, doing your thing within `applicationDidFinishLaunching` instead could help.

See this: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/6200-two-help-menus-why.html

Comment: Well, that's tricky.. because looking at the debug navigator, it seems the `persistentStoreCoordinator:` is being called by `managedObjectContext:`, which is being called by a binding in the main nib/xib file from a `loadNib` function somewhere. So I assume the interface binding is loading before the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` (which makes sense), so I better not use my `NSAlert` there. I'll try moving it elsewhere, I'll update here later, thanks!